# Django End of script output before headers

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

Periodically one of my servers will stop serving content and the following errors are found in the Vhost error log:

```
[Mon Feb 02 10:27:41.692362 2015] [core:error] [pid 13013] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41537] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
[Mon Feb 02 10:27:41.692365 2015] [core:error] [pid 13025] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41188] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
[Mon Feb 02 10:27:41.692423 2015] [core:error] [pid 14787] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:36388] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
[Mon Feb 02 10:27:41.692451 2015] [core:error] [pid 12994] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38770] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
```

After this apache locks up and stops serving content. Help most appreciated.

wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "core.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

vhost:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/zipper/src/core/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess zipper python-path=/var/www/vhosts/zipper/src:/var/www/vhosts/.virtualenvs/zipper/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup zipper

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/zipper/src/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Edit #1

Django version: 1.6.4
Mod_WSGI version: 3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2

Comment: Please add `django` version and `mod_wsgi` version.

Comment: Django: (1, 6, 4, 'final', 0) 

mod_wsgi: libapache2-mod-wsgi              3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2

Comment: Hi Any, how did you fix the issue? I see the same problem on one of my servers. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
ServerAdmin raghav@xyz.com

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/var/www/mysite:/var/www/environ/lib/python2.7/site-packages
#WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/>
order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am also getting the same issue after reading several blogs, this configuration work for me.
Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the directive:

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

after the WSGIProcessGroup line.

There are known issues with various third party Python packages with C extension components that mean they will not work with Python sub interpreters properly. That directive forces the application to run in the main interpreter context. Such modules are then happy.